# how to insert a node in drupal using database query?

Tags: mysql, drupal-6

i want to insert the node manually to drupal database using mysql query. i am using CCK module with path redirect,pathauto & view.
Which tables & which field i will have to feed data so that it will work like a node.

Comment: i am trying to add data to files,node,content_type_cnode,url_alias,path_redirect,node_revisions tables. but still its not forming the node. still somthing is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing I can think of is to insert a node through the Drupal system and see which tables get updated and what with.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to follow the Drupal API way of doing this.

You can take a look at this page http://www.unleashed-technologies.com/blog/2010/07/16/drupal-6-inserting-updating-nodes-programmatically which will help you insert a node with PHP.